# How to subscribe a control in a template to event listener?

Tags: javascript, angular, events

I've added a tag to some of the components in my template like this.

```
<div>...</div>
<div #blopp>...</div>
<div>...</div>
<div #blopp>...</div>
<div #blopp>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

I also do this in the class definition.

```
export class NavBar {
  @ViewChildren("blopp", { read: ElementRef }) blopps: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  constructor() { console.log("NavBar created"); }
  ngAfterViewInit() { debugger; }
}
```

I can iterate over the elements in the debugger using the following script. However, I can't just use `on(event,action)` as I get the error that such method doesn't exist there.

```
blopps.forEach((element)=>{...});
```

Googling gave me something about `blopp.listener(...)` but it seems that my query list doesn't have that method neither. At the moment I feel less than well-oriented so it might be something rather obvious. What am I missing and how can I add events to my template's controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field `blopp` has type [QueryList](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html), it means that it should be processed as in this example:

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer){}

//AfterViewInit interface
ngAfterViewInit() {
   blopps.forEach(elementRef => {
    this.renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (e) => console.log(e));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to changes and specify a type. If your element is native you can do it like this:

```
this.blopps.changes.subscribe(children => {
      //note that children is a collection so you can do foreach here
        children.last.nativeElement.focus();

      // console.log(children.first['_results'][0].nativeElement);                                         
      console.log(children.first);                                          

      // Do Stuff or wire  with referenced element here...   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `toArray()` to get an array that you can iterate over:

```
blopps.toArray().forEach((element)=>{...});
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting the message correctly. I'm iterating over the elements already without using `toArray()`. Is the type cast necessary? What am I iterating over without it? Also, the issue is that I'm not certain how to actually react to the event being fired...